# lodash.isEmpty is resulting in an `eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call` error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, lodash, eslint

This is the error `Unsafe call of an 'any' typed value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call`. Nextjs.

```
const handleSave = () => {
    const temp: string[] = [""]
    if (isEmpty(temp)) temp.push('');
};
```

How do I fix it?

[image: Error picture]